# How to retroactively save an extended Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to extend a Django model using inheritance. I have a custom model like:

```
from request.models import Request

class RequestExtended(Request):
    start_time = DateTimeField(_('start time'), default=None, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    total_seconds = FloatField(_('total seconds'), default=None, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start_time = get_current_request_start()
        total_seconds = None
        if start_time and self.time:
            total_seconds = (self.time - start_time).total_seconds()
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.total_seconds = total_seconds
        super(RequestExtended, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There's middleware in the `request` app that automatically saves a new `request` record for every Django request processed, but this doesn't automatically trigger creation of my extended model. So I tried adding a `post_save` signal like:

```
def post_request_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('request.id:', instance.id, instance.ip)
    RequestExtended.objects.get_or_create(request_ptr=instance)

post_save.connect(post_request_save, sender=Request)
```

However, this throws an error because `RequestExtended` is ignoring my `request_ptr` value and trying to instantiate a blank `Request` instance and not filling in any required fields.

How do you create a model extended through inheritance and link it to an existing record that it's supposed to extend?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, I found [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/pyzra/model_inheritance_question_saving_parents_and/c3tg70z/) that explained the issue.

Even though my model doesn't duplicate the fields in the parent model, because the Python layer simulates my inherited model containing all the fields directly, I need to include all the fields from the parent object when I create it. Otherwise, it tries to set them to blank values, even though I'm specifying the `ptr` object.

So the correct code would be:

```
def post_request_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    o = RequestExtended()
    o.__dict__.update(instance.__dict__)
    o.save()
```